# Rails display simple partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My steps so far: Ive created an new rails app:

```
rails new sample

cd sample

rails g scaffold Post name:string content:string

rails g controller welcome home
```

Next step i added to the welcome/home view one line:

```
<h1>Welcome#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/home.html.erb</p>
<%= render "posts/index" %>
```

Then i copied the code form post/index to post/_index.html.erb

But somehow my partial wont work in welcome/home, my error:

```
NoMethodError in Welcome#home

Showing C:/Sites/sample/app/views/posts/_index.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #12):

9:     <th></th>
10:   </tr>
11: 
12: <% @posts.each do |post| %>
13:   <tr>
14:     <td><%= post.name %></td>
15:     <td><%= post.content %></td>
```

SO what did i wrong?

Comment: `@posts = nil`, does your controller have `@posts = Post.all`?

Comment: Is there another way, so that i dont have to define it new in my controller and simply can reuse the post controller?

Comment: look at https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define @posts in your controller:

```
@posts = Post.all
```

Comment: Is there another way, so that i dont have to define it new in my controller and simply can reuse the post controller?

Comment: No, when you enter the welcome#home route it doesn't load the PostsController. So you have to define it in the WelcomeController as well.

Comment: You could load up the models in the view with Post.all.each but that would not be considered good code.

Comment: can i move that to an helper method?(Rails Beginner)

Comment: I guess, but I would not worry about code duplication in this case. Helpers are mostly used to simplify your views, models are supposed to be loaded in the controller.

Comment: You can put this in your `ApplicationController` in a `before_filter :get_posts`
and then

`def get_posts
  @posts = Post.all
 end
`

and now it's available in all controllers, but that's bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not really need a welcome controller you can keep @posts from posts#index and show another template in the same step using `render`:

class PostsController < ApplicationController 
def index
`@posts = Post.all`
`render 'home'`
end
...

You put `home.html.erb` inside 'views/posts' directory.
If a template you want to render is in 'views/some_other_directory' you can use:
render :file => 'controller_name/template_name'